# Show Form Fields Based Upon User Selection but value won't Submitted

Tags: javascript, laravel

Im doing showing form based on user selection
the displays works well, but the value is not submitted on submit

this is my blade

```
<div class="form-group">
               <label for="category1">Kategori</label>
               <select id="category1" class="form-control" name="metas[kategori">
                         <option value="" disabled selected>-Pilih Kategori-</option>
                         <option value="motor-honda">Sepeda Motor Honda</option>
                         <option value="elektronik">Elektronik</option>
                         <option value="modal-kerja">Modal Kerja</option>
                         <option value="pendukung-operasional">Pendukung Operasional</option>
                         <option value="lainnya">Lainnya <br></option>
               </select>
</div> 

<div class="form-group" id="otherFieldDiv">
      <label for="otherField">Isi Kategori</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otherField" name="metas[kategori]">
</div>
```

this is my js

```
<script>
 $("#category1").change(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == "lainnya") {
            $('#otherFieldDiv').show();
            $('#otherField').attr('required', '');
            $('#otherField').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
          } else {
            $('#otherFieldDiv').hide();
            $('#otherField').removeAttr('required');
            $('#otherField').removeAttr('data-error');
          }
        });
        $("#category1").trigger("change");
</script>
```

***If i choose the "lainnya" value, submit function is success***

but if i choose another value in the console it's returning this

> metas.kategori: The metas.kategori must be a string.